# how to create a view using two tables in different databases in ibm db2

Tags: database, db2

I have got two tables T1 and T2 . T1 is present in database D2 and T2 is present in database D2. I am using DB2 database. I also have two queries  for fetching  data from T1 and T2 respectively.

Now, I have a requirement where I need to create a view and get the combined data of two queries in that view.

For example,  create view testview as select employeeName, employeeGender from sampledb.employee where employeeID >6 UNION select studentName, studentGender from testdb2.student where studentId > 6. 
I want to do something like this.

I have searched a lot on internet for creating a view on different schemas in DB2, but couldn't get a right solution.

Please help.

Comment: kindly Define only the needed tags, your question is realted to DB2, there is no need for tagging the other vendors, plz update yout question via removing the un-needed tags.

Comment: *I am using DB2...* then why did you added `MySQL` and `SQL Server`? Learn how to ask a question properly. Now for your problem; Hint: look into `UNION` probably (OR) `JOIN`

Comment: I have removed the other tags.

Comment: Do you mean SCHEMA or DATABASE? Your example looks like you are referring to databases, although you use schema-related syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you speak schema and not database, this doesn't work?

```
create view t1.viewname (name, gender) as
select employeeName, employeeGender 
from S1.employee 
where employeeID >6 
UNION 
select studentName, studentGender 
from S2.student 
where studentId > 6
```

Comment: I have edited the question. It is database not schema.